# IN operator with static value in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Below is the query:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(vTagName),
       tbl_session_rating.iTagID,
       tbl_tags.iTagID
FROM tbl_session_rating,
     tbl_tags,
     tbl_session_skill
WHERE tbl_session_rating.iSessionID = tbl_session_skill.iSessionID
  AND tbl_session_skill.iID = tbl_session_rating.iSeesionSkilliID
  AND tbl_session_rating.iSessionID = 138
  AND tbl_session_rating.iSkillID = 33
  AND tbl_tags.iTagID IN (tbl_session_rating.iTagID)
```

If I pass static value here `AND tbl_tags.iTagID IN (tbl_session_rating.iTagID)` i.e. `AND tbl_tags.iTagID IN (4,7,6)` then it is giving me correct result, but in current query it is applying `group_concat` for the first (4) id.

What can be the solution?

Comment: Simple. Don’t use GROUP_CONCAT. Ever.

Comment: Issue is in getting `tbl_session_rating.iTagID`. Add your code which deals with tbl_session_rating. I think its only returning a value 4

Comment: @RohitGaikwad `tbl_session_rating` returns comma seprated values

Comment: @Strawberry I want to comma separated tag values